# Firebase android: Retrieving and checking entry to database on button click

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

im new to Android and Firebase programming. Im just building a small app and it works fine so far. But when it comes to the Firebase connection I am struggling. 
I followed all the basic steps and tried a lot but couldnt figure it out.

So my problem: I have a database and it stores IDs: ID --> 12345, 23456, ... , these IDs have multiple childrens (in fact other IDs: ID --> 23456 --> 23456-ValueA, 23456-ValueB, ...). What I would like to do:

1. If a button is clicked the app checks if a previously entered string is a child of ID, so if *enteredstring* matches any of the IDx (for example user enters ValueX("23456") it checks whether any child ofID' equals 23456)
2. If so it should check if another previously entered string is a child of this IDx (users enters  ValueY("88888") check if 23456 Value-A("88888") equals ValueY).
3. If this is true, it should then display the value of Value-B("Ape")

I attached the Database as a picture.[link to the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8VkQ.png)

Thanks for your help, really appreciate it
Cheers

```
...
public class trackid extends AppCompatActivity {

DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference IDRef = rootRef.child("ID");

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_trackid);

            // findViewById
            Button ButtondisplayB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtondisplayB);
            EditText ValueX = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ValueX);
            EditText ValueY = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ValueY);

            // Capture if button is clicked
            ButtondisplayB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    // HERES WHERE MY QUESTIONS START:
                    // if ValueX.getText().toString() is in IDRef.child()
                        //if true: ValueY.getText().toString() equals IDRef.child(ValueX).child(Value-A)
                            //if true: display IDRef.child(Value-B)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
IDRef.child(ValueX.getText().toString())addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if(!dataSnapshot.exists()){
                Log.d("Missing","This id is not present in the database");
            }else{
                String aFromDb = dataSnapshot.child("A-value").getValue(String.class);
                if(ValueY.getText().toString.equals(aFromDb)){
                    String bFromDb = dataSnapshot.child("B-value").getValue(String.class);
                    Log.d("B value is:",bFromDb)''
                }else{
                    Log.d("not equal","A value not equal to ValueY");
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            Log.d("Error",".....");
        }
    });
```

You can change ListenerForSingleValueEvent to ValueEventListener. 
ListenerForSingleValueEvent check the database only once.